# Exporting Datetime from pandas to sqlite results in float format

Tags: python, pandas, database, sqlite, datetime

I have the following dataframe with Entry Time and Exit Time columns.

```
Entry Time  Exit Time
23:03:00    23:55:00
22:46:00    23:55:00
23:03:00    23:57:00
15:59:00    17:51:00
23:17:00    23:48:00
```

Both columns are converted to DateTime initially before getting the above using the following line

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df,format="%H%M", errors='coerce').dt.time
```

What I do next is Export the columns to SQLite Database using the following line

```
df.to_sql(name='time', con=cnx, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

What I expect is to have the columns of Entry Time and Exit Time as they are in Pandas. However, the data is being converted in the database to be as follows.

```
23:03:00.000000|23:55:00.000000
22:46:00.000000|23:55:00.000000
23:03:00.000000|23:57:00.000000
15:59:00.000000|17:51:00.000000
23:17:00.000000|23:48:00.000000
```

How can I keep the same format as in the Dataframe?

Comment: is using dtype string an option? instead of calling `.dt.time` (which gives you a Series of `datetime.time` objects), that would be `.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved as mentioned in the comment by:

```
df = pd.to_datetime(df,format="%H%M", errors='coerce').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```